# Cannot use create-react-app as it shows below error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

PS D:\Reactjs> npx create-react-app textutils

Creating a new React app in D:\Reactjs\textutils.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fscope-manager reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fscope-manager: read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashes10\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-22T05_43_38_991Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting textutils/ from D:\Reactjs
Done.

Comment: is there any proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gonna work

```js
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the cache issue. To fix this, try the below command,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If the issue still persists. Run the below command to install `create-react-app`,

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

And then, Try creating your react application,

```
npx create-react-app appname
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command line as **administrator**
then

- `cd <your desired location to create the project>`
- `npx create-react-app <project name>`